# Mask-image with png-file

Tags: html, css, svg, png, clipping

I have a problem with mask-image: I want to use a png (or svg) as a clipping-mask on an image, so the image is shown in a certain shape. I found several examples online of how to do that, but refer now to this one: https://web.dev/css-masking/.
When I use the png the author used in their example, it works. However, if I use my own png (or svg), it does not.
I made sure the image is reduced to a white fill and a transparent part, just as the one in the example. I also just changed the URL, nothing else. However, the clipped image is not visible.
I know that it is possible to use the SVG in HTML (which would work). However, I need it in CSS.

This is the code I use:

```css
.header_image {
  width: 650px;
  height: 410px;
}

.header_image img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.one {
  -webkit-mask-image: url(https://www.bildhost.com/images/2021/02/21/clipping-mask_4.png);
  /* My own - does not work */
  /* -webkit-mask-image: url(https://cdn.glitch.com/04eadd2b-7dd4-43fc-af3d-cff948811986%2Fstar-mask.png); /* From the example - works */
  mask-image: url(https://www.bildhost.com/images/2021/02/21/clipping-mask_4.png);
  mask-image: url(https://cdn.glitch.com/04eadd2b-7dd4-43fc-af3d-cff948811986%2Fstar-mask.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="header_image">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1567359781514-3b964e2b04d6?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1431&q=80" class="one">
</div>
```

I tried to add the mask-image to head_images, too. Same effect: It works with the example-png but not with mine. So, I assume, there's something wrong with my png, but I can't say, what.

Has anyone an idea where I go wrong?

Comment: open the console and see if you get a red error around CORS security thing

Comment: the image you are using as a mask is **partly white partly transparent**. Please try using an image with black and white

Comment: @TemaniAfif That was the problem, I could use the png after using imgur. How odd, I never had problems before with this hoster. Thank you very much, I would not have though of that!

Comment: @enxaneta Thanks for your suggestion. I tried to use a black and white image (after changing the uploader), it did not work, however. I assume this is because you need a transparent part that actually "clips" the image.

Comment: In fact you need a **black** _part that clips the image_. Please take a look at this demo: https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/dPYJKJ Also read the article: https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/ Please take a look at the image used as a mask

Comment: @enxaneta As stated before: my png with a white shape worked perfectly well, as you can see here: https://codepen.io/kreuzkoenig/pen/MWbvZMR - I can see that the tutorials use black shapes, although I could not find any mentioning that the shape had to be black, white or any other color.

Answer (score 0):

Your image does not have any transparent background.
I used photoshop to cut your picture with a transparent background then upload on the server.

Note the trick behind case 3 is to make your masks in black and white.

white will be the visible part, the actual shape you want to be visible
black is uqual to transparent so it will not be visible.

Not sure what part you needed so I did 3 versions of the clip masks:

```css
.header_image {
  width: 650px;
  height: 410px;
}

.header_image img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.one {
 -webkit-mask-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/QdYThVvx/clipmask1.png);
  mask-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/QdYThVvx/clipmask1.png);

}
.two {
 -webkit-mask-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/bvG2Jpj0/clipmask2.png);
  mask-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/bvG2Jpj0/clipmask2.png);
}
.three {
 -webkit-mask-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/kMb8dxQj/clipmask3.png);
  mask-image: url(https://i.postimg.cc/kMb8dxQj/clipmask3.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="header_image">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1567359781514-3b964e2b04d6?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1431&q=80" class="one">
    <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1567359781514-3b964e2b04d6?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1431&q=80" class="two">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1567359781514-3b964e2b04d6?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1431&q=80" class="three">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, by uploading my original png (which indeed had a transparent background) I could solve the issue. I did not have to change the background or any other part to transparent or black (as @enxaneta also mentioned). The issue was the CORS security error, as Temani Afif wrote.